# fedora: dnf check update/installed packages without sudo privileges

Tags: fedora, package-management, dnf, software-updates

I do not have sudo-rights and I want to

- force to check for updates
- to check if a package is installed or can be installed

Answer (score 1):

`dnf check-update`

If you want to force to refresh
`dnf --refresh check-update`

Other dnf-commands without requiring sudo are:

```bsh
dnf check-update
dnf list installed
    
#for a specific package (I take firefox as an example)
dnf list firefox
dnf search firefox
dnf list installed firefox
rpm -q firefox
which firefox
firefox --version
```